# SVN Commit denied. Error "can not open file txn-current-lock"

Tags: svn, permissions, centos, commit

I am installing a SVN server (v1.6) on a VPS contracted with CentOS 5, Apache 2.2 with WHM panel.
I installed and configured all necessary modules and am able to create and access repositories via my web browser normally.

### The problem is:

I can not commit or import anything, I always return error:

```
Error: Can not open file '/[path]/svn/test/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

I've read and execute permissions on numerous tutorials regarding this error, all without success.
I'm using TortoiseSVN to connect to the server.

### Some information you may find useful:

- I'm trying to perform commit through an external HTTP connection.
- SELinux is disabled.
- I've changed the owner of the folders to the user/group apache `chown -R apache: apache /var/www/svn`
- I defined 777 permission to all folders and files `chmod -R 777 /var/www/svn`
- Running the command to see the active processes of Apache, some processes are left with user/group "nobody". I tried changing the settings of Apache to not run with that user/group, but all my websites stopped working.

Apache process list:

```
root@vps [/var/www]# ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
root     19904  0.0  4.4 133972 35056 ?        Ss   16:58   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
nobody   20401  0.0  3.5 133972 27772 ?        S    17:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
root     20409  0.0  3.4 133972 27112 ?        S    17:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
nobody   20410  0.0  3.8 190040 30412 ?        Sl   17:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
nobody   20412  0.0  3.9 190344 30944 ?        Sl   17:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
nobody   20414  0.0  4.4 190160 35364 ?        Sl   17:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
nobody   20416  0.0  4.0 190980 32108 ?        Sl   17:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
nobody   20418  0.3  5.3 263028 42328 ?        Sl   17:01   0:12 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
root     32409  0.0  0.1   7212   816 pts/0    R+   17:54   0:00 egrep (apache|httpd)
```

SVN folder permission `var/www/`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 16:41 svn/
```

Repository permission `var/www/svn/`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 16:41 test/
```

Internal folders of repository `var/www/svn/test`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 16:41 conf/
drwxrwxr-x 6 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 16:41 db/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 apache apache    2 Dec 11 16:41 format*
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 16:41 hooks/
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Dec 11 16:41 locks/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 apache apache  229 Dec 11 16:41 README.txt*
```

Comment: Well, 2 options: (1) don't run apache as nobody (but 'something' went wrong apparently) or (2) make 'nobody' owner of the svn repo (or possibly, writable for 'nogroup'. Despite appearances nobody tends to be somebody on most os's I've come across.... (3) make your 'nobody' apache instance proxy to another apaches instances wich actually runs like apache on another port.

Comment: @Wrikken I already tried to set *nobody* as owner, but doesn't work too. Regarding the problem in Apache, I don't know the cause of problem in change "nobody" to "apache".

Comment: Hm, well... if 'nobody' doesn't work either...  not having worked with CentOS for a while I'm out of ideas then. If you can't set up the proxy, I'd ask again @ serverfault.com. (used to be we could vote to move questions there, seems to be gone now...)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @odyodyodys No, I gave up implementing SVN. I intend to eventually implement Git, but now I'm out of time to see this.

Comment: @FredWuerges Thanks. Eventually we chmod-ed to 777 the whole repos in order to be able to commit. Centos-Subversion1.5.0